# Saving HTTP_REFERER in django

Tags: python, django

I have the following code in Django:

```
def signup(request)
    http_referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','/')
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    else:
        if request.method == 'GET':
            # return HttpResponse(http_referer) Here it returns the right value
            args={}
            return render(request,'signup.html',args)
        elif request.method =='POST':
            # return HttpResponse(http_referer) Here it breaks and returns current url
            ... actual code goes here, but this should be enough
```

I want to save the `HTTP_REFERER` for later use, because it is being changed. I have tried storing it in variable, but somehow variable still automatically changes. I guess I could try storing it temporarily in database (it probably won't change there), but since I only need it in that function and never again, that seems like a bad solution. Is there a better way of doing this?

**EDIT**

Okay now I feel pretty stupid, as I realize I was saving `http_referer` on every request (`POST` would auto change it and I would save that change), instead of saving it only on `GET` requests to the session like user below suggested :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could store http_referer in a key storage, like [Redis](http://redis.io/), for a more robust solution.

Or you could try adding http_referer in session, like this: request.session['http_referer_foo'] = 'bar'

Comment: OK, that is better than database solution but I still think that there must be something more simple that works.

Comment: Did you try adding http_referer in session, like this:
request.session['http_referer'] = 'bar'

Comment: OK I realized my mistake, and adding it to the session works perfectly, thanks :)